# ElasticSearch 6.x and NEST simple query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Actually I'm a newcomer to ElasticSearch and got stuck with just a simple NEST query. 
Here is my class to store data in ElasticSearch:

```
public class MyClass
{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get documents by the Language (e.g. Language == "eng")
I use the NEST 6.x

Here is the SerchDescriptor

```
searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<MyClass>()
                .Index(indexName)
                .Query(q => q.Term("Language", "eng"));
```

it produces the request:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "Language": {
        "value": "eng"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but the right request is

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "Language": "eng"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get the right request via NEST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both forms are valid**; the former is the [long form of `term` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/term-query-usage.html) that accepts other properties such as `boost` and `_name`.

NEST typically serializes request types to the long form, and deserializes from the long form.